# If the last surviving human mutates to an alien, do they win with the aliens?

Tags: escape-from-aliens-in-outer-space

In Escape From Aliens in Outer Space, one of the item cards is the Mutate card, which turns a human into an alien. The rules say that the human then plays as an alien from then on. However, if the last surviving human plays that card and mutates into an alien, does the game immediately end with an alien victory, with that converted alien winning as well? We had that happen in our game today, and it felt like an unsatisfactory ending.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the rules book, humans loses only when killed by aliens. Therefore it seems logical that a mutated human wins with aliens even if he is the last one.

Said this, I agree with you, this is definitely an unsatisfactory winning. To avoid it, I suggest you to set as "house rule" that the Mutate card cannot be played by the last human. This will make the human to fight for his life!

Comment: I am not sure if I would agree with that house rule as having this situation come up is not something that would happen easily as not only does the player have to be lucky enough to draw the item but also be the sole surviving human in the game. I think in situations like that it is okay for that person to share in the win and with that shortened time it might be possible to get in another round of this or a new game.

Comment: Force them to fight? To me, this is just another way to introduce strategy. Do you think you're highly likely to be killed? If so, you may want to switch sides in order to win! And if you're the aliens, then why wouldn't you want the last human to become an alien? Win-win! I'm against that proposed house rule for those reasons.